# Publish Webjob in Visual Studio fails with no error

Tags: azure, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for some help troubleshooting why a Webjob publish fails. This has been working for months, without issue. The application works fine if I copy the executable manually to the app service, compile works, everything seems fine, but the webjob public fails with no error just this irritating red bar.

I've tried various combinations of publish settings, created a new App Service, and no luck. Are there some traces I can check somewhere ?

[Image of no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2rUa.png)

[No Errors in the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9vEE.png)

Comment: Can you share the publish settings ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, settings here: https://imgur.com/a/iNwpHf8

Answer (score 0):

Its should be working, below sample azure webjob sample deploying .net core console application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Check you publish settings, it should be working as expected

Comment: Hi Rahul, here is a screenshot of the settings.  https://imgur.com/a/iNwpHf8

Comment: While selecting the application which option you have selected webjobb or webapp ?? You can try with simple app as the per the above screenshot and it will work 